# JSON Parsing using jQuery - Deep Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have read a lot of Questions here but could find any answer for my Problem with Multidimensional JSON Arrays. I want to just to parse the Tag "countdown" but my Code get only up to the Array "departureTime". Any other change has no result to show the "countdown" tag.

My JSON

```
    {
    "data": {
        "monitors": [
            {
                "locationStop": {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point"
                    }
                },
                "lines": [
                    {
                        "departures": {
                            "departure": [
                                {
                                    "departureTime": {
                                        "timePlanned": "2016-02-13T23:03:00.000+0100",
                                        "timeReal": "2016-02-13T23:03:39.000+0100",
                                        "countdown": 13
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "departureTime": {
                                        "timePlanned": "2016-02-13T23:33:00.000+0100",
                                        "countdown": 43
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "departureTime": {
                                        "timePlanned": "2016-02-13T23:48:00.000+0100",
                                        "countdown": 58
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am parsing like here

```
success: function(data) {
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    var departure = json.data.monitors[0].lines[0].departures.departure;
    $.each(departure, function(i, item) {
        $.each(item, function(i, type) {
            console.log(type);
            $('#results').append(type);
        });

    });
}
```

Adding a third $.each is not working in any way, I added to $each(departure.departureTime) and to $.each(item.countdown) but this give me Errors too. I am not a developer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
success: function(data) {
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    var departure = json.data.monitors[0].lines[0].departures.departure;
    $.each(departure, function(i, item) {
        $('#results').append(item.departureTime.countdown);
    });
}
```

Comment: Ohh my God! Never thought about the append. Thanks a lot!